What's the recommended way to connect AWS Glue to Snowflake?
AWS Glue now provides Snowflake connector as outlined here - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/snowflake-connectivity-aws-glue-apache-spark/. How is this connector different from the one outlined here ? I am looking to understand if there are any performance benefits of using one over the other for a Glue Spark Job that loads data to Snowflake?
I am trying to understand if with the launch of the latest AWS Glue Connector for Snowflake, is the below option redundant? If not, which one provides better performance?
https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/?lang=pt-br
